# Find Result as Non Zero Value in Group of Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe as below:

```
    SYS     Date_Time                Col_1 Col_2   Col_3  Col_4   Col_5  Col_6
0   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:15:00      0     0       0      0       Y      0
1   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:20:00      0     0       0      0       0      0
2   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:25:00      R     0       0      0       0      0
3   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:30:00      0     0       0      0       0      0
4   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:35:00      0     0       0      0       0      0
5   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:40:00      0     R       0      0       0      0
6   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:45:00      0     0       0      0       0      0
7   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:50:00      0     0       0      0       0      0
8   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:55:00      0     0       0      0       0      0
9   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 10:00:00      0     0       0      0       0      0
10  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 10:05:00      0     0       0      0       0      0
11  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 10:10:00      0     0       0      0       0      0
12  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 10:15:00      0     0       0      0       0      G
13  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 10:20:00      0     0       0      0       R      0
14  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 10:25:00      0     0       0      0       0      0
```

I need to find the result color in column group of (Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4, Col_5, Col_6) where the color is not Zero.

Two possible condition can exist in above dataframe:

1. Only one out of 6 columns will be Non Zero.
2. If all columns have Zero Value then result will be Zero.

I want the Output as below:

```
    SYS     Date_Time                Col_1 Col_2   Col_3  Col_4   Col_5  Col_6 Result
0   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:15:00      0     0       0      0       Y      0     Y
1   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:20:00      0     0       0      0       0      0     0
2   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:25:00      R     0       0      0       0      0     R
3   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:30:00      0     0       0      0       0      0     0
4   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:35:00      0     0       0      0       0      0     0
5   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:40:00      0     R       0      0       0      0     R
6   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:45:00      0     0       0      0       0      0     0
7   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:50:00      0     0       0      0       0      0     0
8   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 09:55:00      0     0       0      0       0      0     0
9   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 10:00:00      0     0       0      0       0      0     0
10  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 10:05:00      0     0       0      0       0      0     0
11  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 10:10:00      0     0       0      0       0      0     0
12  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 10:15:00      0     0       0      0       0      G     G
13  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 10:20:00      0     0       0      0       R      0     R
14  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07 10:25:00      0     0       0      0       0      0     0
```

Comment: Does all the non zero values can contain only alphabets?

Comment: Yes, all the non zero values will be alphabets only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using the following code:

- `join` all the columns that have 'Col_' in them, using a `lambda` function in `apply`
- `replace` all the numeric characters with '' which will keep only alphabets
- Lastly, `replace` '' with 0 to get exactly your output.

```
df['result'] = df[[c for c in df.columns if 'Col_' in c]].apply(lambda row: ''.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1).str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '').replace('',0)
```

which prints:

```
        SYS  Date_Time Col_1 Col_2  Col_3  Col_4 Col_5 Col_6 result
0   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     Y     0      Y
1   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     0     0      0
2   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     R     0      0      0     0     0      R
3   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     0     0      0
4   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     0     0      0
5   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     R      0      0     0     0      R
6   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     0     0      0
7   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     0     0      0
8   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     0     0      0
9   SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     0     0      0
10  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     0     0      0
11  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     0     0      0
12  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     0     G      G
13  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     R     0      R
14  SYSTEM1 2021-01-07     0     0      0      0     0     0      0
```

There probably is a better more pythonic way to do this, but this is a one-liner and does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) the `Col` like columns, then change the `dtype` of these columns to `str` and take [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) along `axis=1`. **The idea used here is that when you take `max('0', some_alphabet)` then the returned max value will always be `some_alphabet`**:

```
m = df.filter(like='Col').astype(str).max(1)
df['Result'] = m.where(m.ne('0'), 0) # replace '0' with 0
```

---

```
0     Y
1     0
2     R
3     0
4     0
5     R
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    G
13    R
14    0
Name: Result, dtype: object
```